# Highcharts: Show tooltip anywhere over series value column without using shared:true?

Tags: highcharts

Probably a stupid sounding question, but I want my Highcharts column tooltip to display when I mouseover anywhere above or on the column, but I don't want to use the tooltip shared:true attribute.

I'm doing this because my client has some columns that are tiny compared to their neighbors. It would be nice if the mouseover worked before I got close to the tiny columns.

Screenshot of what I'm trying to ask:
[image]

[Here is a fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/red5/x06zoyb5/7/).

```
Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'column'
    },
    title: {
        text: 'Find Tauntauns'
    },
    subtitle: {
        text: 'Some site on the web'
    },
    xAxis: {
        categories: [
            'Jan'
        ],
        crosshair: true
    },
    yAxis: {
        min: 0,
        title: {
            text: 'Tauntauns'
        }
    },
    tooltip: {
        headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:10px">{point.key}</span><table>',
        pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
            '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:.1f} mm</b></td></tr>',
        footerFormat: '</table>',
        //shared: true,
        useHTML: true
    },
    plotOptions: {
        column: {
            pointPadding: 0.2,
            borderWidth: 0
        }
    },
    series: [{
        name: 'Tokyo',
        data: [7]

    }, {
        name: 'Hoth',
        data: [83.6]

    }, {
        name: 'London',
        data: [48.9]

    }, {
        name: 'Berlin',
        data: [5]

    }]
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, this option is not available from the API for the column series type because the `pointTracker` functionality works different than for the other series like a line or scatter.

My idea to achieve the wanted result is rendering dummy/transparent rectangles which will trigger the tooltip on mouseover effect.

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/3pr4baeq/

```
events: {
  render() {
    let chart = this;

    chart.series.forEach(s => {
      s.points.forEach(p => {

        if (p.customRect) {
          p.customRect.destroy();
        }
        p.customRect = chart.renderer.rect(p.barX + chart.plotLeft, chart.plotTop, p.pointWidth, p.shapeArgs.y)
          .attr({
            //fill: 'transparent',
            fill: 'yellow'
          })
          .add();
        p.customRect.element.onmouseover = function() {
          chart.tooltip.refresh(p)
        }
      })
    })
  }
}
```

You can change the color of the rendered rectangles to the transparent which will hide them.

API: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.SVGRenderer#rect

API: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/chart.events.render